# jquery ui draggable forbidden over an element

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I'm using jquery ui draggable, I do not want to let the user drag the helper over another element, how can I do this? I can not use snapMode: outer.

Thank you.

Comment: The effect you're looking for does not follow the draggable widget's metaphor. Usually, in your situation, the dragged element is allowed to go over the other element, but gets reverted to its initial position if dropped there. Would this behavior be suitable enough for your needs?

Comment: Hi Frederic, I think it can work, may I need the droppable ui?

Comment: I can not set a void element because i want the user drag it on free space... or maybe can i set as valid droppable the entire document?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my previous comment, I meant to set the `revert` option to `"invalid"`. In your situation, you want the opposite, i.e. set the `revert` option to `"valid"` and create a single droppable widget around the element you do not want the helper to be dragged to. I'll try to elaborate on that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [revert](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert) draggable option for that purpose.

If you set it to `"valid"`, the drag operation will be reverted if the helper is dropped on a droppable widget. That means you only have to create such a widget around your other element:

```
$("#yourDraggableElement").draggable({
    revert: "valid"
});

$("#yourOtherElement").droppable();
```